# How to present region in Google query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I am using rails geocoder. So far just been using it directly not via ActiveRecord/Mongoid etc.

I would like to in my Google request specify the region, e.g. 'au'

What do I need to in combination with (or instead of) Geocoder.search to achieve this?

Comment: how about `Geocoder.search("Paris", :region => 'au')` ?

Comment: @tihom thanks that worked :-) seems so obvious but I hunted through the docs and couldn't find. make it an answer if you like.

Comment: cool added the answer with link to docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Geocoder.search("Paris", :region => 'au')`, the gem uses Google as the default API and the parameters that Google API accepts are given [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#GeocodingRequests)